# Does react native always renders everything when state changes?

Tags: react-native, performance, expo, rendering, use-state

I would like to know if when a state changes only the component affected by the state and all its children are rendered or "the whole function (the return part) where that component is".

*Example*

```
const [label,setLabel]=useState();
...
export default function MyFunc(){
...
  return (
      ...
      (more than 200 rows of code)
      ...
      (here i have the button)
      ...
      (more then 200 rows of code)
  )
}
```

When somewhere setLabel it's called, whenever it happens does React render everything included the other rows of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Whenever there is change in state react re-renders the component. That is the concept of react.

If your component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

For more info, visit the below link,

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo